# How to add glui to working freeglut project?

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, glut, freeglut, glui

I have a working project containing freeglut and glew.
I want to add buttons and menu bar to the project, by using GLUI . 
So the question is , how can i add GLUI linker to the project? , meaning header and libraries and make it all work together easiest way possible.

bottom line, i have problems with defining the external dependencies to the project , in order to add the glui.

Answer (score 0):

I have a program that's using GLUT and GLUI running on Ubuntu and i use the following libraries:

```
#include <GL/gl.h> 
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glui.h>
```